# Can nightwatchjs be configured to run against selenium grid via command line vars?

Tags: selenium-grid, nightwatch.js

Can `nightwatchjs` be configured to run against `selenium grid` via command line vars?

I use to run `mocha tests` against the `selenium grid` in this way:

```
SELENIUM_REMOTE_URL=http://selenium.dev.com:4444/wd/hub 
    ROOT_URL=https://username:password@docker-branch.com mocha test/basic.js
```

I've been searching through all the `nightwatchjs.org/guide` info and been combing through stack overflow articles, however, I haven't found a way to send in both selenium grid hub URL and root URL of the project to test.

The docs seem to indicate that I can do this through the `nightwatch.json` the configuration file, however, my root URL is going to be constantly changing so I need to have it be a command line parameter if possible.

Any insight would be great, thank you!